# Why isn't the scalar product of a covector and vector symmetric?

Tags: differential-geometry

In tensor math, how come the scalar product of a co-vector (co-variant vector) with contra-variant vector, as written between angle bracket separated by comma, $\langle x, a \rangle$, is not symmetric?

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this maths question?

Answer (score 3):

$\def\cV{{\cal V}}$
I don't know the book you quoted and am not interested in it. It's simply wrong, according universal use in mathematics, to call your $\langle x,a\rangle$ a scalar product.

Given a vector space $\cV$ on a field $K$, its *dual space* $\cV^*$ is defined as the set of linear functions 
$$x: \cV \to K,\quad a \in \cV \mapsto \langle x,a\rangle \in K$$ with linearity defined as usual.

This is possible for whatever vector space, with no other special structure required for it. It can easily be shown that $\cV^*$ can be given the structure of vector space on $K$. Elements of $\cV$ are called *vectors*, those of $\cV^*$ are called *covectors*. Of course it would be meaningless to write
$$\langle x,a\rangle = \langle a,x\rangle$$
as $a$ and $x$ belong to different spaces.

A scalar product is a structure of $\cV$ not always required or useful. When required it's defined as follows.

A scalar (inner) product on $\cV$ is a bilinear,  symmetric, non-degenerate mapping 
$$\cV \times \cV \to K,\quad 
(a,b) \in \cV \times \cV\ \mapsto\ a\cdot b \in K.$$
Here $(a,b)$ means the *ordered couple* of two vectors. Bilinear means separately linear on both $a$ and $b$. Symmetric means
$$\forall a,b:\ a\cdot b = b \cdot a.$$
Non-degenerate means
$$(\forall a:\ a \cdot b = 0)\ \Rightarrow\ b = 0.$$

*Note*: Alternative definitions are in use, somewhat different in some properties. Also the notation for inner product is not firmly established and may especially differ between mathematics and physics.

In a vector space with scalar product a covector can be defined using scalar product, as follows. If in $a\cdot b$ we keep $a$ fixed a linear function $\cV\to K$ is defined:
$$x: \cV \to K,\quad a \in \cV\ \mapsto\ 
x \cdot a \in K.$$
This member of $\cV^*$ we may denote by $a^*$. Here is the cause of the confusion, frequently done, between scalar product and dual space.

The question arises: with the above definition of $a^*$ every element of $\cV^*$ is obtained varying $a$ in $\cV\,$? The answer is negative without further hypotheses on $\cV$ and on the scalar product.

But here I must stop.

Comment: Thanks i got the answer . But the online notes by Mr Sharipov is a celebrated one.(URL: http://www.geocities.com/r-sharipov.) I am yet to reach to end. But in any case thanks..

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a confusion in your question. You speak of "scalar product" in a case that could potentially be non-symmetric (according to your description), but by definition, a scalar product is a bilinear **symmetric** positive definite form. So you must have misunderstood something in your original source of information. Do you have a reference that would help us to clarify the bit you actually don't understand. As it is, the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I was going through  Quick Introduction to Tensor Analysis: by R. A. Sharipov. As per the same scalar product of co-vector and vector is not symmetric and moreover one cannot swap the position. That is to say first argument must be co-vector. However this is not so disturbing a proposition.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a scalar product. By definition a 1-form $\omega$ takes a vector $v$ as input and gives a scalar $\omega(v)$ as output. As 1-forms and vectors are different entities, symmetry of the operation does not even make sense.

It is true however that the more symmetric notation $\langle\omega,v\rangle$ is sometimes used. It stems from the fact that if your manifold is equipped with a non-degenerate bilinear form $g$, typically a metric, you get an isomorphism between the space of 1-forms and that of vectors. To the form $\omega$ it associates the vector $\omega^\sharp$ defined $\omega(v)=g(\omega^\sharp, v)$ for any vector $v$. In components the isomorphism is just the "raising indices" operation you may be familiar with. If $g$ is a metric then it is symmetric and $g(\omega^\sharp, v) = g(v,\omega^\sharp)$. Writing $\langle, \rangle$ for $g$ and identifying forms and vectors because of the isomorphism leads to the notation $\langle\omega, v\rangle $.

I should note that the notation $\langle\omega,v\rangle$ is sometimes used even if no preferred isomorphism between vectors and 1-forms has been chosen. We may discuss wether or not it is good notation, in any case it does not represent a scalar product.